# Ignore Conda virtual environments in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda, virtual-environment

I have Python versions and virtual environments managed by Pyenv. I use them to work on projects using Visual Studio Code.

I also have Conda (from Anaconda package) installed to run Jupyter notebooks. I never want to use conda environments in VSCode (I am not even sure if they are of the same type as normal virtual environments, never was able to fully wrap my head around this).

Is there a way to hide all existing and future conda-managed Python versions and conda (virtual) environments from VSCode when I am choosing an interpreter there?

Comment: you can make an alias of pythonv to the local python not managed by condo or Pyenv. And then in your config for VSCode use pythonv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible for now. [Where the extension looks for environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_where-the-extension-looks-for-environments).

The extension automatically looks for interpreters, and haven't provided any settings to change this default behavior. If you really want to change it, you only can modify the extension to change the logic of interpreter searching. I tried, but sorry, I can't find out where it is.